# How much time is required for layover in Dubai airport?

Tags: layovers, short-connections, dxb

My travel agent offered me a flight with Emirates, that arrives at Dubai airport at 13:05, and the next leg exits at 14:30.

1. Is this time (85 minutes) sufficient for the layover?
2. In case the incoming flight is late and I miss the next flight (both are by Emirates), what should I do - can I simply go to the Emirates stand and ask for a replacement?

Comment: To clarify, is this booking through a travel agent? I assume that’s what ‘TA’ means in this context, but short acronyms are almost always ambiguous if there’s no prior context establishing the meaning, and I can think of half a dozen other possible meanings (some of which would make sense here in some cases).

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn yes, fixed

Answer (score 6):

Depends on the details and I'm assuming that this is a single ticket and an international to international connection.

> Is this time (85 minutes) sufficient for the layover?

Should be ok. Minimum Connection time in Dubai for international to international is 60 minutes

> In case the incoming flight is late and I miss the next flight (both are by FlyEmirates), what should I do - can I simply go to the FlyEmirates stand and ask for a replacement?

Yes. As long as you can remember to name of the airline correctly. (probably Emirates or FlyDubai). If you miss a connection on a single ticket by no fault of your own, the airline will rebook you for free. "no fault of your own" is important. If both incoming and outgoing flights were on time and you still missed it, the airline will want to know WHY you missed it.